# Find the parametric equations for the line spanned by the vector $u=(3,-2,5)$

Tags: linear-algebra, parametrization

This seems too easy, so i might be wrong.
The parametric equations of a line consist of a point on the line and a vector parallel to the line.
If the vector $u$ spans the line, then we can use this vector as the parallel vector. The point $(0,0,0)$ will be on the line so the parametric equations would be:
$ x = 3t \\
y = -2t \\
z = 5t
$

Is that right? there is no answer in the back of the book for this one.
Thanks.

Comment: ok thanks for the edit. @Jose

Comment: Your analysis is correct.  "The" parametric equation(s), however, is perhaps a bit misleading.  For example, $x=t$, $y = -2t/3$, and $z = 5t/3$ also gets the job done, no?

Comment: Oh yeah, good point. "Candidate parametric equations could be..." or something like this, Thanks @XanderHenderson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is right. Your argument is correct.

Comment: Thanks for verification @Jose.

Comment: @Bucephalus Perhaps that you could mark my answer as the accepted one.

Comment: I can, but it makes me wait 10 minutes. I tried before it said I actually had 11 minutes to wait before I can accept it. Only 3 minutes to go now.

Comment: You answer is like a comment. It's far from fruitful posts!

Comment: @MyGlasses I think that for every question, if there is an answer which is seen (by the person who asked the question) as the correct answer, then the answer should be marked as such, so that other users may realize that the person who asked the question is satisfied. That's why I asked Bucephalus to mark my answer as the accepted one, but I did *not* ask to upvote it. Had I done so, and your remark would be correct.